# How do you append one UWP IRandomAccessStream to another without using .Net managed stream

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to append without using .Net methods?
Or are they even zero cost to use?

```
IRandomAccessStream sourceStream;
IRandomAccessStream destinationStream;

// This uses .Net managed stream but I want to avoid that
sourceStream.AsStream().CopyTo(destinationStream.AsStream());
```

Comment: Could you tell why don't use  .Net methods to append ?

Comment: My desire is to only use UWP native code. Doesn't calling out to .Net methods impose a performance penalty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to append without using .Net methods?

I think you could use byte array as agent to approach.

**For IRandomAccessStream to byte[]**

```
async Task<byte[]> Convert(IRandomAccessStream s)
{
    var dr = new DataReader(s.GetInputStreamAt(0));
    var bytes = new byte[s.Size];
    await dr.LoadAsync((uint)s.Size);
    dr.ReadBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

**For byte[] to IRandomAccessStream**

```
async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> ConvertTo(byte[] arr)
{
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await randomAccessStream.WriteAsync(arr.AsBuffer());
    randomAccessStream.Seek(0); // Just to be sure.                   
    return randomAccessStream;
}
```

**For concatenate byte arrays**

```
byte[] combined = bytesOne.Concat(bytesTwo).Concat(bytesThree).ToArray();
```